# Target specific class with setInterval and function with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working with a script to randomly toggle classes on a set of images. So far it works as intended, but the one thing I was wondering if there is a way to target a specific class since it appears to target the `window` and I'm not sure that the best way to go about it.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
var counter = 0;
$('.images img').each(function(i) {
  if (i == 0) {
    counter = 0;
  } else {
    counter++;
  }
  if (counter < 5) {
    $(this).addClass('show');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('hide');
  }
});

function shuffleRandomLogos(remove, add) {
  const logo = $("." + remove).toArray();
  const logoLength = logo.length;
  const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * logoLength);
  const randomLogo = logo[randomNum];
  $(randomLogo).removeClass(remove);
  $(randomLogo).addClass(add);
}

window.setInterval(function() {
  shuffleRandomLogos("show", "hide");
  shuffleRandomLogos("hide", "show");
}, 600);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300" alt="">
</div>
```

I've tried to update `const logo = $("."+remove).toArray();` to this:

`const logo = $(".images img").toArray();` which *works* but then it starts to break out of first 5 to be shown and starts getting a little crazy.

So not sure what I need to adjust to just have it target the `.images img` or if there is a better way to go about it.

Here's a link to a demo (CodePen):
https://codepen.io/ultraloveninja/pen/gJRqPM

Comment: Make sure there is a space after `img` in your selector otherwise you could be accidentally making the wrong selector, eg `img` would become `imghide` and hence the selector wouldnt match anymore

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add random classes at first, just call function manually and later in interval. Also remove all `.show` classes and add only to selected ones.

Also note that you should move preparation variables out of function for faster processing.

```js
var logos, logosLength;

function makeImages(count)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    $('.images').append('<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.png?text=' + i + '">');
  }

  logos = $(".images img");
  logosLength = logos.length;
}

function shuffleRandomLogos(count)
{
  logos.removeClass('show');
   for (var i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
      let randomLogo = logos[Math.floor(Math.random() * (logosLength - 1))];

      $(randomLogo).addClass('show');
  }
}

makeImages(20);
shuffleRandomLogos(5);
window.setInterval(function () {
    shuffleRandomLogos(5);
}, 600);
```

```css
.images img {
  display: none;
}

.images img.show {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
</div>
```

Comment: This would be great if all of the image names and URL's would be the same, but I'm planning on using this within a WordPress theme/application and not all of the images that will be uploaded will have the same filename.

Comment: @ultraloveninja Images generator is just for example, I was too lazy to write all links by hand :D

Comment: Ahhhhhh, ok. yeah, after messing with it, I was wondering if I could have just omitted the `for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    $('.images').append('<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.png?text=' + i + '">');
  }` and just run with it. Thanks!

Comment: Been messing with this a bit more and I can get it to _almost_ work, but I'm also trying to show only 5 at a time and then shuffle between those. So close...

Comment: @ultraloveninja So simply put random selector to loop. I have updated my answer, but it still possible to show less then 5 elements - same image is selected to be shown multiple times